# Bootstrap Range slider is Not working in Bootstrap Modal POP Up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

Bootstrap slider is not working in Bootstrap Modal POP UP. But working correctly in Page .

My Modal PoP Up

```
<div class="modal fade" id="divonloadserach" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Search</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="500" data-slider-max="20000" data-slider-step="0" data-slider-value="[1500,9000]" id="Range">
                    </div><div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this i have given the id as range , And the same slider is mentioned in page with different slider. This pop up window will be open when the page was loaded

My java script code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#divonloadserach').modal();
        $('#Range').slider();
}
```

Please Help Me